# GWT serialize a class extending a TreeSet

Tags: java, gwt, serialization, arraylist, treeset

I have a GWT shared-package class as follows:

```
public class MyCustomClass extends TreeSet<MyCustomType> implements Serializable, IsSerializable {
     // ... a whole bunch of methods
}
```

I am trying to send an instance of the class as an object encapsulated in another class, through RPC.

The problem is the `TreeSet`, as GWT refuses to serialize it, no matter what I do. I get an error during runtime:

> SEVERE: my-service: An IncompatibleRemoteServiceException was thrown while processing this call.
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IncompatibleRemoteServiceException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: http:
>       at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.decodeRequest(RPC.java:323)

So, I have all the serialization pre-requisites (default constructor, no final fields, getters and setters, all my instance variables are serializable, implement interfaces, etc.), but this continues to happen.

The thing is, when I switch from `TreeSet` to using an `ArrayList` instead, **everything works fine**. In my understanding, this is because I am already using `ArrayList`s in a number of services, so GWT knows to whitelist it in the serialization policies.

That understanding came because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9369256/serializing-jdbc-types-in-gwt) thread. And I've tried the proposed solution from the accepted answer (create a "dummy" service and put a `TreeSet` there, I even created a dummy class in my client package and put a `TreeSet` as a field), but no luck.

I checked my .gwt.xml just in case, the `TreeSet` is not added as a serialization exception.

So, I am pretty much stuck at this point, my workaround is to use the ArrayList and re-pack it into a transient set, but I do not really like that approach.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

(using GWT 2.6)

**Update:** `MyCustomType` implements the `Comparable<MyCustomType>` interface, and there is no custom comparator provided to the `TreeSet`.

Comment: Does `MyCustomType` implement `java.lang.Comparable`?

Answer (score 0):

May be `MyCustomType` doesn't implement `java.lang.Comparable`

It works fine for `ArrayList<MyCustomType>` but not for `TreeSet<MyCustomType>`

---

--EDIT--

**`HashSet<MyCustomType>` or `LinkedHashSet<MyCustomType>` are working fine.**

After getting data at client side just use

```
new TreeSet<MyCustomType>(<retured HashSet<MyCustomType>)
```

There is no need of iterating it because it is ordered by `<Comparable<MyCustomType>`.

Comment: It does implement Comparable<MyCustomType>, so it must be something else :/

Comment: OK Let me figure it out.

Comment: All the model classes are implementing `IsSerializable` and `Serializable`, Right?

Comment: Yes, they are. Like I said, as soon as I switch from TreeSet to ArrayList (everything else remains the same), everything works.

Comment: `HashSet<MyCustomType>` or `LinkedHashSet<MyCustomType>` are working fine.

Comment: Hmm... that doesn't really give me any advantage over the ArrayList, except for removing duplicates.

The HashSet doesn't guarantee iteration order, and the LinkedHashSet only keeps insertion order.

I need to often use an Iterator to go through my elements, and potentially remove them, if I re-pack the collection into a sorted TreeSet that doesn't really help me much...

Comment: There is no need of iterating it because it is ordered by `<Comparable<MyCustomType>`. See updates in my answer. Its working fine. May be you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Your problem statement *I need to often use an Iterator to go through my elements, and potentially remove them* is resolved by using any of `Set` and What is harm of finally putting data back to `TreeSet` at client side.

Comment: Sorry, had been away for a few days. Anyway - ok, I _can_ find a workaround, without a doubt, but that still doesn't solve the original issue - why can't a pure TreeSet-extending-class be serialized normally, like all other collections?